# How can I limit the order of the integration that the scipy solve_ivp integrator is allowed to build to nothing higher than 1st order?

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

Question is as above. After reading the documentation, I can change the integrator itself (RK45,RK23, DOP853, etc), however I cannot find information on the order of these integrators, or on ways to limit the integrator to 1st order.

How can this be done? Do I have to use a particular ODE solver method that is by default 1st order, or can I edit any method to be 1st order?

Comment: The documentation for the list of solvers, the `method` kwarg, describes the order for each. E.g., `RK45` is of order 5 or 4, for different aspects of the solver. If you want to limit the solver to be first order, I think you'd need to implement your own [`OdeSolver`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.OdeSolver.html#scipy.integrate.OdeSolver).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where do you see kwarg? It doesn't seem to be on the page I'm looking at: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html. I think implementing my own is out of my league so I'll aim to find an existing 1st order one if possible

Comment: It's the 4th parameter from the top, named `method`. It lists the builtin integration methods, with their orders where applicable. One can also specify an `OdeSolver` if you have special requirements, which sounds like you might.

Comment: Ah I see. Do you see the 'BDF' integrator? It seems to be the only potential integrator that could do 1st order integration. It offers order from 1st to 5th. However it does not say how to implement this. Do you know how to specify 1st order here?

Comment: It looks like the order is [automatically selected](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.BDF.html), presumably on the basis of the data. Usually, one picks an integrator for its properties, such as convergence, stability, etc, rather than requiring any particular order. I'm not an expert here, but it sounds like you'll need to implement your own solver if that's a hard requirement.

Comment: Yes it seems so. Its not a hard requirement I just thought the order of the integrator I'm using was causing unusual results in a model I'm working on. I wanted to check lower orders to confirm. I will look into implementing 1st order if I can't find another solution. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many integrators, the order is a fixed property. There are some methods – let’s call them *meta integrators* – that switch between different integrators, but they are still limited to the order of these integrators. Thus, you cannot simply control the order of the integrator and leave everything else the same.

If you really want a first-order method, it’s easy to implement the [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) – unless you want [step-size adaption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_step_size).

Mind that the order of an integrator denotes how its error behaves for small step sizes. In this respect, a higher order is nothing that should cause a problem per se. I would therefore find it remarkable if using a first-order method solves a problem. Sometimes, individual methods can have problems or the problem is [stiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation), but here the solution is to use another solver (for stiff problems), not a first-order solver. If you consistently observe a result for all solvers, it is by far more likely that this your true result or you made a mistake defining your derivative or similar.